# Finding the length of string wound on a cube.

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

> Consider a cylinder of height $h$ cm and radius $r = \dfrac2π$ cm as shown in the figure (not drawn to scale). A string of a certain length, when wound on its cylindrical surface, starting at point A and ending at point B, gives a maximum of $n$ turns (in other words, the string's length is the minimum length required to wind $n$ turns)

[image]

In light of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205917/finding-vertical-spacing-between-string-wound-on-the-cylinder)  it has a second part.

> $2.)$The same string, when wound on the four exterior four walls of a cube of side $n$ cm, starting at point C and ending at point D, can give exactly one turn (as shown in the below figure).The length of the string in cm is ?

[image]

[image]

By opening the cube the skeleton will look like the above with string in red color.

**Options**

$a.)\quad \sqrt2\cdot n\\
\color{green}{b.)\quad\sqrt{17}n}\\
c.)\quad n\\
d.)\quad\sqrt{13}n$

> $3.)$ And hence now conclude the from problem $1.)$ and $2.)$ relation between $h$ and $n$.?

**Options**

$a.)\quad h=\sqrt2\cdot n\\
b.)\quad h=\sqrt{17}\\
\color{green}{c.)\quad h=n}\\
d.)\quad h=\sqrt{13}n$

from the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205917/finding-vertical-spacing-between-string-wound-on-the-cylinder)  length $=\sqrt{h^2 + 16 n^2}$.
Now how do i use the data with the occurence of cube of side $n$ cm

Comment: $\sqrt{n^2 + (4n)^2} = \sqrt{h^2+16n^2} \implies 17n^2 = h^2 + 16n^2 \implies \ldots$

Comment: @achille : Ok so the $b.)$ and $c.)$ are correct for question $2.)$ and $3.)$ ? .

Comment: Yes, b. and c. are answers for Q2. and  Q3. The key is both surfaces are "flat". You can "unfold" the surfaces as planes and uses the ordinary Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: $\quad$ Ok Thanks!